# Split an array in 2 lists, loop through second list

Tags: node.js, express, for-loop

Say I have an array ie. cities (with n items) that I wish to split into two similar sized lists and loop through both lists separately.

The first list is not a problem (see below):

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < cities.length/2; i++)  {%>
<li class="mb-2"> <i class="<%=cities[i]%> w-1rem mr-3 text-center"></i><span class="text-sm"><%=cities[i]%></span></li>
<% } %>
```

However, how can I make sure the second list only starts looping half way through the index(say if i = 10, then from index 5 to 10). I have tried the below unsuccessfully...

```
<% for(var i = cities.length/2; i < cities.length; i++)  {%>
<li class="mb-2"> <i class="<%=cities[i]%> w-1rem mr-3 text-center"></i><span class="text-sm"><%=cities[i]%></span></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I can't see your second list in your codes.

Comment: I've updated it, so effectively use (cities.length/2) as a starting point and loop until the end of the array (cities.length)

Comment: If i understands your question, you need to use two nested for loops which second one depends to first ones index.

Comment: Thank you Vahid! Appreciate it